# Why is my CSS3 Transition not working in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, css

It's working elsewhere on the site using the same CSS as far as I can tell. 
It works in Chrome.
 Here is the full page: anthonyotislawrence.com

Here's the part that's not working:

```
<a class="socialBox linkedIn">
    <h3>LinkedIn</h3>
    <p>linkedin.com/anthonyotislawrence</p>
</a> 
<a class="socialBox facebook">
    <h3>Facebook</h3>
    <p>facebook.com/anthonyotislawrence</p>
</a>
```

and the CSS

```
.socialBox {
    display:block;
    min-width:200px;
    padding:4px 0 4px 55px;
    height:40px;
    line-height:20px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:left center;
    position:relative;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-out;
    transition: all .5s ease-out;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin:30px 0;
}
.socialBox.linkedIn {
    background-image:url(../images/linkedin.png);
}
.socialBox.facebook {
    background-image:url(../images/facebook.png);
}
.socialBox:hover {
    left:15px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.socialBox:hover p {
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have practically the same structured css as you in my project and I have the same problem in FF... I think it is to do with the background-image property ... I changed my background-image:url(../images/linkedin.png); to just a plain background to see if the transition would work and it did... background: #fff; ... that doesnt solve it still but it just indicates that it is to do with using transition on background-image.. i'm still looking for solutions...

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It looks like FF wont transition default values. They have to be declared on the original element before it will transition to the new properties.

Comment: I'm doing what is suggested in this answer, and still no beans. I'm trying to transition top, and opacity, and it isn't animating.

Comment: thank god.. you just saved me so much time. Ben, you are a boss

Comment: @Ben Hi, I have practically the same structured css as this in my project and I have the same problem in FF... I think it is to do with the background-image property ... I changed my background-image:url(../images/linkedin.png); to just a plain background to see if the transition would work and it did... background: #fff; ... that doesnt solve the problem but it just indicates that it is to do with using transition on background-image.. i'm still looking for solutions... any ideas? thanks

Comment: @Ben me again.. actually i've just found out that background-image is not an animatible property... this makes sense now.. http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-properties

Comment: The background-image itself is not animatible, but the position should be.  Also looking around, it seems it's not a standard but some browsers might also animate/transition background-size property.

Comment: I am sorry, but this answer is completely nebulous. Do you mean you have to add in-line styles to the element? If so, please use the correct language.

Answer (score 4):

I had an issue similar to the OP where my transitions worked in every browser except Firefox.  In my case I had intervals of zero seconds.  I used just a 0 and not 0s.  This caused the transition to not work at all in Firefox.  I don't think this was the issue for the OP but posting here in case it helps someone else.

This does not work in Firefox:

```
top 0 linear 1s
```

This works:

```
top 0s linear 1s
```