# What is wrong with transitions in Firefox 18

Tags: css, firefox, css-transitions

I have this code

```
nav {
   background-color:#600;
   padding:3px 0;
}
#menu {
   list-style: none;
   position: relative;
   text-align: center;
   z-index: 50;
}
#menu li {
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
   height: 40px;
   width:100px;
   max-width: 100%;
}
#menu li a {
   color: #000;
   text-decoration: none;
   display: block;
   position: relative;
   height: 40px;
   padding: 10px 15px 0;
   font-family: Berlin Sans FB;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
   -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
   -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
   -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}
#menu li span {
   width: 6px;
   z-index: -1;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   height: 100%;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
   -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
   -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
   -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
   transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
}
#menu li:nth-of-type(1) span {background: green;}
#menu li:nth-of-type(2) span {background: red;}
#menu li:nth-of-type(3) span {background: #ff8400;}
#menu li:nth-of-type(4) span {background: purple;}
#menu li:nth-of-type(5) span {background: #49a7f3;}
#menu li:nth-of-type(6) span {background: yellow;}
#menu li:hover > span {min-width: 100%;}
#menu li a:hover {color: #fff;}
#menu li:hover {box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 20px 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/burn123/2SjHN/)

It has worked fine in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox<18. It doesn't work in Internet Explorer or Firefox 18. Is there something that was changed in this version of Firefox that has changed how transitions are working?

I looked at this question and the accepted answer, but it didn't make sense
[Why is my CSS3 Transition not working in Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084268/why-is-my-css3-transition-not-working-in-firefox)

Comment: Can you explain what's wrong? Also, where is your HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems changing the width to a value other than `min-width` causes it to work properly in Firefox 18/Mac....

```
 #menu li:hover > span {
  width: 100%;
 }
```

[Fiddle update](http://jsfiddle.net/2SjHN/6/)

As Ben pointed out in the question you linked to, FF seems to want declarative values.

Comment: Interesting. Could you possibly explain why this is?

Comment: Edited answer.. and Ben answered it in your linked question. FF seems to need actual values to calculate. It can't calculate ambiguous numbers such as `min-width`.

Comment: Why not? If it worked in the previous versions why wouldn't it work now?

Comment: I'm not a FF developer.. it may be a bug.

Comment: What changed is that per spec the initial value of `min-width` used to be 0, but now it's `auto` (see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=763689 ).  And also per spec you can't interpolate between `auto` and `100%`...  This is arguably a spec bug, actually.  In any case, you can set `min-width: 0` in your case that doesn't have a min-width to work around this for now.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a version of Firefox 18 for me to test on right now, but after looking at your code, I believe that you are missing an unprefixed version of the `transition` property

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2SjHN/5/)

```
transition:all 0.2s ease-in;
```

According to [Can I Use?](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions), Firefox has already supported the non-prefixed version.

Comment: Even if this isn't what's wrong, he does need to add `transition` without a prefix somewhere. Nice catch.

Comment: but this has worked in all the previous versions, so why would i need to add that now? And the link still doesn't work. But nice looking

Comment: @CodyGuldner 1) According to _can i use_, prefixed version was never implemented in IE10 (so IE "obviously" doesn't work); 2) Since this is a W3C recommendation, all browsers will eventually support the non-prefixed one (so adding it will make your site work more consistently), and then very likely to drop prefix support in later version (this does has already happen on some properties, though I can not remember one right now).